# Scala key/value case class to Json

Tags: scala, playframework, play-json

Given the following case class:

```
case class ValueItem(key: String, value: String)
```

and the following json formatter:

```
implicit val valueItemFormat: Format[ValueItem] = (
        (__ \ "key").format[String] and
        (__ \ "value").format[String])(ValueItem.apply, unlift(ValueItem.unapply))
```

a json representation of a ValueItem instance like

```
ValueItem("fieldname", "fieldValue")
```

is

```
{ "key" : "fieldName" , "value" : "fieldValue" }
```

I'm wondering how to get a json in a flat key/value serialization like

```
{ "fieldName" : "fieldValue" }
```

Comment: I suspect you might have to define separate Reads and Writes instead of using Format for this one.

Comment: Yes, that's a good point. I've already been there but I've faced the problem of finding the proper jspath with no parameter name, but knowing the position. Something like "key" comes before "value"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't think of a nice way to do this using combinators, since most approaches there require a more direct way to map values at paths to case class fields.

Here's a solution that'll work for objects like `{"fieldName" : "fieldValue"}`.

```
import play.api.libs.json._
import play.api.data.validation.ValidationError

implicit val fmt: Format[ValueItem] = new Format[ValueItem] {

    def reads(js: JsValue): JsResult[ValueItem] = {
        js.validate[JsObject].collect(ValidationError("Not a key-value pair")) {
            case JsObject(Seq((key, str: JsString))) => ValueItem(key, str.value)
        }
    }

    def writes(v: ValueItem): JsValue = Json.obj(v.key -> v.value)

}
```

I've resorted to defining `reads` and `writes` manually, as you can see. The `Reads` is the tricky part, as we're not used to pulling path names into case classes. We can `validate` the object as a `JsObject` first, then `collect` only objects that match the exact structure we're looking for (only one key-value pair, where the value is a `JsString`). The `Writes` is much more straightforward, as `Json.obj` can do exactly what we want.

In action:

```
scala> Json.parse(""" { "fieldName" : "fieldValue" } """).validate[ValueItem]
res0: play.api.libs.json.JsResult[ValueItem] = JsSuccess(ValueItem(fieldName,fieldValue),)

scala> val item = ValueItem("myKey", "myValue")
item: ValueItem = ValueItem(myKey,myValue)

scala> Json.toJson(item)
res2: play.api.libs.json.JsValue = {"myKey":"myValue"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Play released it's module for dealing with JSON independent from Play Framework, [Play WS](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaWS)

Made a blog post about reading JSON to case classes, but write is pretty similar. check it out at http://pedrorijo.com/blog/scala-json/

Using case classes, and [Play WS](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaWS) (already included in Play Framework) you case convert between json and case classes with a simple one-liner implicit

```
case class User(username: String, friends: Int, enemies: Int, isAlive: Boolean)

object User {
  implicit val userJsonFormat = Json.format[User]
}
```